# Can Murch deliver gears with unlocked ability slots if I order them from a player who has them?

Tags: splatoon-3

In Splatoon 2, players could order up to three pieces of gear from other players with the help of [Murch](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Murch), and this is still possible in Splatoon 3.

Morover, giving him some [Super Sea Snails](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Super_Sea_Snail) it's possible to increase gear's star power with the first and second stars each **adding an ability slot to the initial one**. You can also increase star power outside of Murch by purchasing duplicate gear in the shops.

So I'm wondering:
If I order an "enhanced" gear from another player (who paid to add more slots), is there any chance to receive the boosted gear version with more ability slots already unlocked? Or will I always receive the standard version of that gear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, when ordering Murch merch, you will always be able to buy the basic version of the item, like if it showed up in the shop.

So any upgrades/changes made to the item you do not get for free.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same impression.. I'll try to test this a bit more.